# How can I create drawFeature control in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I want to call a callback on leaflet after drawing a feature.
In openlayers I do it like this :

```
customControl= new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
                    tempLayer,
                    OpenLayers.Handler.Point,
                    {
                        title: 'Custom Control',
                        displayClass: "olControlClass",                        
                        featureAdded: onCustomControlCallback
                    });
```

How can I do the same in leaflet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leaflet draw plugin is similar to openlayers draw control. see 
 https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#drawdrawstop